# mysqldump how to put inserts on one line per table (not wrapped)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've got a situation (a script) where I want all `INSERT INTO` of a table on a single line (not wrapped) in the mysqldump output.

I know how to do the opposite (place every row in a new insert on a new line).
That you can do by adding **`--extended-insert=FALSE`** resulting in this **(too many lines for me):**

```sql
LOCK TABLES `TimeSlot` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TimeSlot` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50021,'A','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50022,'B','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50023,'C','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50024,'D','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50025,'E','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TimeSlot` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Changing the command to **`--extended-insert=TRUE`** results in this **(lines wrapped, too many lines):**

```sql
LOCK TABLES `TimeSlot` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TimeSlot` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50021,'A','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),
(50022,'B','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),
(50023,'C','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),
(50024,'D','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),
(50025,'E','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TimeSlot` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The result I would like to get is this **(insert on line line):**

```sql
LOCK TABLES `TimeSlot` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TimeSlot` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `TimeSlot` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `year_id`) VALUES (50021,'A','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),(50022,'B','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),(50023,'C','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),(50024,'D','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10),(50025,'E','2020-02-06 09:33:46','2019-03-04 09:08:08',10);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TimeSlot` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

The full command I am currently using (resulting in a single but wrapped output):

```
mysqldump \
    --single-transaction \
    --net-buffer-length=16384 \
    --no-create-info \
    --skip-add-drop-table \
    --disable-keys \
    --extended-insert=TRUE \
    -c -u username -psecret --host=mariadb --port=3306 test ;
```

Is there a way to tell mysqldump to *not wrap* lines?

Comment: I doubt. Linebreak have no special meaning in SQL, it is trreated as common space symbol. The form does not affect the content in any way, mysqldump should make the dump correct, but it should not make it beautiful. You may do this in any external text editor or programmatically.

Comment: I have to ask. WHY?

Comment: MySQL's version of mysqldump does not put in newlines. Tuples are output in a single line by default. This must be a difference in MariaDB's fork of mysqldump.

Comment: I found the change in MariaDB, they did it deliberately, they say it was to make the output easier to work with when using tools like grep or diff: https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/586d6a2520de23d8e5a3cc6ccfd29dbd728dba69 So I guess the answer to your question is to use MySQL's clients, not MariaDB's.

Comment: But even if using MySQL's clients, you won't get _all_ the rows of the table on a single line. The output terminates the INSERT statement and starts a subsequent statement if the set of tuples exceeds `net_buffer_length`. That's necessary because there's a finite limit to the length of any SQL statement.

Comment: The why is this: I have a Bash script that dumps the database and then table-by-table replaces every insert statement in a seeder written in JavaScript (and modifying every backtick `\`` by placing an escape character before it).
In the seeder every table is one line and to match one line in the dump with one line in the seeder is easier than multiple lines.

Comment: I know there is the `net_buffer_length`. My seeder is only for seeding the test database (i.e. the database used for automated testing) and I would not expect the contents of the test database to grow that large (default is 16384, my longest insert is currently 5057 characters).

Comment: It might work to set `max_allowed_packet` to a really low value, such as "10".  And then use it with `--extended-insert=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Bill Karwin contains the correct answer:
[In newer versions of Mariadb it is not possible anymore](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/586d6a2520de23d8e5a3cc6ccfd29dbd728dba69)

**Also, note** that putting a whole table in one insert can cause problems if tables get too big, which can be fairly quick. Mysql might not be able to execute such long lines.

Luckily (for me, for now) a simple *sed* command can join wrapped lines.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# run mysqldump
dump() {
  mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-info \
   --skip-add-drop-table --disable-keys --extended-insert \
   -c -u username -psecret --host=mariadb --port=3306 test ;
}

# join wrapped lines and output to file
dump | sed -z 's|),\n|),|g' > dump.sql
```

Now I have a dump.sql file with every insert on one line :-)